# What is the difference between for (int I = 0; I<n; I++) and int I; for (I = 0; I < n;I++)?

Tags: c, for-loop, declaration

I have a code like this for question 53 of leetcode:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int solve(int arr[], int size)
{
    int lmax, qmax, tmp, i, j,  m = (size / 2) - 1;
    for (i = m, tmp = 0, lmax = arr[m]; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        tmp += arr[i];
        if (tmp > lmax)
        {
            lmax = tmp;
        }
        else
        {
            lmax = lmax;
        }
    }
    for (j = m + 1, tmp = 0, qmax = arr[m + 1]; j < size; j++)
    {
    
        tmp += arr[j];
        if (tmp > qmax)
        {
            qmax = tmp;
        }
        else
        {
            qmax = qmax;
        }
    }
    return lmax + qmax;
}
```

If i change this code block:

```
int lmax, qmax, tmp, i, j,  m = (size / 2) - 1;

for (j = m + 1, tmp = 0, qmax = arr[m + 1]; j < size; j++)
{
   
    tmp += arr[j];
    if (tmp > qmax)
    {
        qmax = tmp;
    }
    else
    {
        qmax = qmax;
    }
}
```

to this

```
int lmax, qmax, tmp, i, m = (size / 2) - 1;

for (int j = m + 1, tmp = 0, qmax = arr[m + 1]; j < size; j++)
{
   
    tmp += arr[j];
    if (tmp > qmax)
    {
        qmax = tmp;
    }
    else
    {
        qmax = qmax;
    }
}
```

which is i change to

> int lmax, qmax, tmp, i, m = (size / 2) - 1; -> int lmax, qmax, tmp, i, j,  m = (size / 2) - 1;

> j -> int j

My output is printing different results, I could not find the meaningful explanation of this, in "int j" situation I can print correct "qmax" values in scope but when I tried to do "lmax + qmax" it returns sum of addresses.

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Comment: @Yigithan Yigit The change does not influence on the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the type inside the `for` you are **creating** a new variable (in your case three variables: `j`, `tmp`, and `qmax`). If there are **other** variables with the same name, they are [*shadowed*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) until the loop terminates.

```
int solve(int arr[], int size)
{
    int lmax, qmax, tmp,i, j,  m = (size / 2) - 1;

    // qmax exists here

    for (int j = m + 1, tmp = 0, qmax = arr[m + 1]; j < size; j++)
    {
        // loop with different j, tmp, and qmax
    }

    // back to old uninitialized qmax

    return lmax + qmax; // this qmax does not have the value you "want"
}
```

gcc has the option `-Wshadow` that may help in this case.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your answer but i can not understand why `int j` affects, i am just doing in scope operations with `j` and i dont need `j` in outscope, right? So why it is changing the result even doing in scope operations. Thank You Again!

Comment: Yes, doing `for (int j = 0, k = 1, l = 2; ...)` possibly shadows all of `j`, `k`, and `l`, not just `j`. **Your problem is shadowing of `qmax`**.

Comment: @pmg I understand right now. If all variables are pre defined for for-loop then for-loop kinda passing initialization sequence and using global variables.